# How to set root password?

Tags: linux, passwords, root, lxc

I followed installation instruction in Linux container homepage.

After lxc-create command, I selected Ubuntu, Trusty, i386 and then a message was shown:

> Use lxc-attach or chroot directly into the rootfs to set a root password
>   or create user accounts.

So, I moved to `~/.local/share/lxc_03/rootfs` and ran `sudo chroot .` Then I tried to change password but failed:

```
root@user_id:/# passwd   
Enter new UNIX password:    
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: System error  
passwd: password unchanged
```

What could be causing this?

My environment: Ubuntu 14.04 running on Parallels

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you followed instructions on some publicly available page, it might be a good idea to include the link to the page in your question. You can edit your question any time, there is a link for that below the tag list.

Answer (score 0):

Go up a level. Try 'chroot rootfs'
Then type 'passwd'

Regards, kevkiller